# How to get a list in ajax call Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask based application, where I have an input for pictures upload. It is possible to upload up to 5 pictures, and I want to get all the files' names and pass them to a view function.
Here is my JavaScript

```
$.post('/new_ad', 
            {
                title: $('input[name=title]').val(), 
                instrument: $('#instrument option:selected').text(), 
                price: $('input[name=price]').val(), 
                description: $('textarea').val(),
                photo: ['one', 'two']
            }, 
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
        });
```

I've hardcoded photo parameter, for testing purposes.
In the view function I try to get it with:

> photo = request.args.getlist('photo')

but every time I receive an empty list.
Can anyone explain what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=args#flask.Request.args) gives you the arguments from the query string (in other words, it would have the values of `key` if your URL was `/home?key=5`).

Since the jQuery `post()` call sends the data as form data, you want to use the [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=request#flask.Request.form) attribute. Optionally, you could also use [`request.values`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=request#flask.Request.values) which has the content of both `request.args` and `request.form`.

See [The Request Object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object) section of the tutorial for more info.